# Extracting a word from a message in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a message that is of the format:

```
FixedWord1 variable1 FixedWord2 on FixedWord3 variable2/variable3, variable4 = variable5
```

I need to extract only variable3 from the above message.

Here is what I tried:

```
String example = "FixedWord1 variable1 FixedWord2 on FixedWord3 variable2/variable3, variable4 = variable5";
```

I know that the length of FixedWord3 is 6. So,

```
example.substring(example.lastIndexOf("FixedWord3") + 6 , example.lastIndexOf(","));  //To get {variable2}/{variable3}
```

And then,

```
String requiredString[] = example.split("/", 2);  //requiredString[1] would contain {variable3} even if it contains /
```

Can you suggest a more efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: Will the final string also have braces around the variables? Or are you just using them as placeholders here?

Comment: The braces are just placeholders. The final string will not have them.

Comment: Your split would not work properly since both variable2 and 3 can have '/'

Comment: @Vivek - I have modified my answer and based on the comments I've read it returns what you are after on my IDE based on the string you gave us from the regex site.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: if you want reviews of working code for optimizations use https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This is not a duplicate. The initial code didn't even work. Show me the duplicate if you're going to mark it as one.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - NONE of the so-called duplicate answers can answer this question. You are mistaken to label this a duplicate. Did you even read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
This regex should do the trick.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+(Device).+[/]([A-Z].+)[,][ ].+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourstring);
if(matcher.matches())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
```

Assumption to make this work:

- Variable2 has no slash '/' followed by upper case letter
- Variable3 has no comma ',' followed by space ' '

Comment: Thanks D.Rek. I cannot use lastIndexOf("/") because I expect {variable3} to contain a / too.

Comment: does the variable or the fixed word before variable3 contains '/'?
if they don't you could still use `example.substring(example.indexOf("/"), example.lastIndexOf(","));`

Comment: This could work if the previous words don't contain a '/'. But I can't assume that at this point.

Comment: Okok, i'm trying to find a solution with regex, stay tuned ;)

Comment: @Vivek if you can't assume that variable2 or variable3 don't have '/' you have a problem. Because even if you have just variable2/variable3 string you can recognize which '/' is a separator and which is just part of the variable. There are a few solution to this: A. don't allow '/' in variable2 B. don't allow '/' in variable3 C.change separator

Comment: Just if you know that variable2 or variable3 as a fixed number of occurence of '/' this problem wold became solveble

Comment: I've understood the pattern, but can you confirm that variable2 or variable3 will have a specific number of '/'? If the answer is no, we will need more information on possible value for varible to solve this.

Comment: For example in your link variable3 has just one '/'. Can you assume that all the possible values for variable3 will have 1 '/' (no more nor less).

Comment: There is the possibility to use the fact that in Interface name '/' occurs just before a number and all Interface name starts with a letter. I'll try to use that in a regex.

Comment: Also, I believe variable2 which is the device name will not contain a '/'. It can have '-' however.

Comment: Last edit, i've tested this. it works.

Comment: @D.Rek did you actually go and -1 every person who wasn't you to discredit their answers?

Comment: Of course i didn't. Don't know hot to prove it, but no, i didn't

Comment: @ChrisSharp if any of you are miscreants [1](https://ibb.co/iOVnAw) [2](https://ibb.co/bQHCcb)

Comment: @D.Rek I had to look that word up. What bad behavior have I displayed? You are the only person here who did not get downvoted and I was downvoted at almost exactly the moment you announced your answer. If you didn't then you didn't. It was a valid assumption though.

Comment: @ChrisSharp miscreants is also a synonymous for unbeliever. Anyway there is no reason to keep this talk, i'm now going to upvote al the other answer that does work, so you'll recive my upvote.

Comment: I've no idea who did it or why, but thanks for your honesty. And thanks for teaching me something about regex.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that variable2 cannot contain a "/" and you know the length of FixedWord3 then how about this?

```
    String deviceName = example.substring(example.lastIndexOf("Device") + 6, example.lastIndexOf(","));
    String lastPart = deviceName.substring(deviceName.indexOf("/") + 1);
    System.out.println(deviceName);
    System.out.println(lastPart);
```

Prints:

> SJ-ME3600X-185/GigabitEthernet0/4
>
> GigabitEthernet0/4

Comment: No clue on variable3 size.

Comment: Ah. I misread that part of the problem.

Comment: @D.Rek - how about this edited answer? I based it on the info you gathered from Vivek.

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution. I'm trying to make similar thing with regecx

Comment: This answer returns the correct value based on the parameters gained by comments from Vivek. Why was it downvoted?

Comment: Thanks ChrisSharp and @D.Rek for your help. The question was marked as duplicate and someone has downvoted the question and all the answers. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Of course who did this didn't even read the question. None of the question above fully answer your Q.

Answer (score -1):

Regex for the help.

One possible approach is catching the match that's after "{variable2}":

```
{variable2}\/{([^}]+)}
```

Then you can use [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and maybe other tools to make it work in Java.

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/2l5Z0Z/1) for explanation and live demo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Maroun. But the problem is I don't know what variable2 would look like. I only know the format for the fixed words.

Comment: @Vivek Then replace `variable2` with `.*`: https://regex101.com/r/2l5Z0Z/2

Comment: The braces around variables were just placeholders. The actual message doesn't contain them.

Comment: @Vivek Then remove them :) How about something like that: https://regex101.com/r/2l5Z0Z/3?

Comment: I just edited the question to reflect the same.

Answer (score -1):

Using Regex patterns are the efficient way to extract the word from a message in java.

```
String s  = "FixedWord1 {variable1} FixedWord2 on FixedWord3 {variable2}/{variable3}, {variable4} = {variable5}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/(\\{([^}]*)\\})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output** {variable3}